# I made my own sudo command in windows, but if i run a program via file-path then it doesnt count the spaces

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

if i type "sudo "C:\Whatever with space\file.txt"" then the output is "The command "C:\Whatever" is either misspelled or
could not be found."

```
set "sz=%2 %3 %4 %5 %6"
if /I "%c%" EQU "" goto cmd
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process cmd \"/k %sz%\" -Verb RunAs"
goto exit
:cmd
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"
goto exit
```

Comment: so ... why are you using bad/cmd stuff to start powershell? why don't you use powershell directly?

Comment: @CrystalPixl, if the above reading of your intent is correct, it is unclear where the `%c%` variable comes from, and why you're not using `%1`, or, more generally, why  you're not using `%*` to reference all arguments received. Also, note that the elevated `cmd.exe` will have `C:\Windows\System32` as its working directory, not the caller's.

Answer (score 0):

The "quirks" of `cmd.exe`'s parameter parsing make a robust solution really difficult; here's a solution that:

- Starts the elevated (run-as-admin) `cmd.exe` session in the same working directory as the caller.
- Supports passing commands with the following limitations:

  - Passing a *single* command and its argument should work as-is, even with quoted command names / arguments; e.g.:

    ```sh
    :: Also works if the arguments contain spaces.
    sudo "notepad.exe" "c:\windows\win.ini"
    ```
  - *Multiple* commands, incorporating *operators* such as `&`, `|` and `>`, require escaping the operators with `^^^` (sic).

    ```sh
    sudo echo "hi there" ^^^| findstr "there"
    ```

**`sudo.cmd` source code**:

```sh
@echo off & setlocal

set args=%*

if %1.==. (
  powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs '/k cd /d \"%cd%\"'"
) else (
  powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs '/k cd /d \"%cd%\" & %args:"=\""%'"
)
```